# Scala Spark: Best way to create column for ranges

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

i am looking for a way to improve and reduce the lines of duplicate code. I need one column for each range. Is there a way to create a method which can handle the column generation here?

```
df
  .withColumn(
    "daysbetween",
    fn.datediff($"date1", $"date2")
  )
  .withColumn(
    "0",
    fn.when(
      $"daysbetween" >= -30,
      $"TotalPrice"
    )
  )
  .withColumn(
    "-30",
    fn.when(
      $"daysbetween".between(-60, -31),
      $"TotalPrice"
    )
  )
  .withColumn(
    "-60",
    fn.when(
      $"daysbetween".between(-90, -61),
      $"TotalPrice"
    )
  )
  .withColumn(
    "<-90",
    fn.when(
      $"daysbetween" < -90,
      $"TotalPrice"
    )
  )
```

Its bad in two ways. Firstly, i have a lot of duplicate code. Secondly, i am using magic numbers which is a problem i need to solve too.

I would appreciate your help guys.

Greetings Joe

Comment: if you have only the above cases a select should be enough `df.withColumn("daysbetween", fn.datediff($"date1", $"date2"))
  .select(
   $"daysbetween",
    fn.when($"daysbetween" >= -30,$"TotalPrice").as("0"),
    fn.when($"daysbetween".between(-60, -31), $"TotalPrice").as("-30"),
    fn.when($"daysbetween".between(-90, -61), $"TotalPrice").as("-60"),
  )`. If this is not the case and you have much more cases you will need o for loop based mechanism to populate the columns

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis
thanks alexandros, i think your solution is better than mine!

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code helps
I have created list of columns tupling it with name. NOt sure if you are looking to auto generate the column generation logic

```
val dynamicCols : List[(String, Column)] = List(
      ("daysbetween",
         fn.datediff($"date1", $"date2")
      ),
      ("0", fn.when(
      $"daysbetween" >= -30,
      $"TotalPrice"
    )),
      ("-30", fn.when(
        $"daysbetween" >= -30,
        $"TotalPrice"
      )),
      ("-30",
        fn.when(
          $"daysbetween".between(-60, -31),
          $"TotalPrice"
        )),
      ("-60",
        $"".when(
          $"daysbetween".between(-90, -61),
          $"TotalPrice"
        )),
      ("<-90",
        fn.when(
          $"daysbetween" < -90,
          $"TotalPrice"
        ))
    )

    val df  = dynamicCols.foldLeft(df)((df : DataFrame,colInfo : (String,Column)) => {
      df.withColumn(colInfo._1,colInfo._2)
    }
    )
```